# Elasticsearch How to remove specific index settings

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Below is my index settings

```
{
   "schools": {
      "settings": {
         "index": {
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "provided_name": "schools",
            "creation_date": "1501821788813",
            "analysis": {
               "filter": {
                  "synonym": {
                     "ignore_case": "true",
                     "type": "synonym",
                     "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt"
                  }
               },
               "analyzer": {
                  "synonym": {
                     "filter": [
                        "synonym"
                     ],
                     "tokenizer": "standard"
                  }
               },
               "tokenizer": {
                  "default_tokenizer": {
                     "type": "standard"
                  }
               }
            },
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "uuid": "GnnZjVLqR7yaxcwhwABtbQ",
            "version": {
               "created": "5050199"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I want to remove the synonym filter so that synonym filter does not work. How can I remove the specific setting from it. I tried to updated it using PUT but it merge the data rather then removing it. Any Ideas ?

Comment: did you close the index before the PUT, as explained here? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html

Comment: Yes as mentioned I am able to update it. But I want to remove the setting from index. What is the way do to that? Or If I can disable it?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761372/updating-analyzer-within-elasticsearch-settings You need to reindex the data