# Does changing from Simple Analyzer of Elastic search to Standard Analyzer requires the re-index?

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer, reindex

I changed the `simple analyzer` on a field to `Standard analyzer` and tested it locally and it's working fine. I don't have to re-index all my documents in ES.

But according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761372/updating-analyzer-within-elasticsearch-settings) SO post and [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/reindex.html) ES doc, looks like we need to re-index if we add/change the analyzer on a field.

I am confused as its working fine now and it would take consider amount of time if I do the re-indexing and want to avoid it, if it's not required.

Let me know if somebody faced the similar situation and what they did ?

Edit :- I am using the ES 1.7 version and I changed the analyzer on a field and just started the app again, I think my app just update the latest mapping to ES.

Comment: If you change an analyzer, of course you need to reindex your data, or at the very least the field whose analyzer was changed.

Comment: @Val , But as I mentioned, its working fine for me, don't know how although.

Comment: As far as I know you can't actually change the analyzer on an existing field. How did you change it? Did you confirm it actually changed like you expected (checking the mapping api)? (I've just tried it with ES 5.6.3 and it behaves as I expect -- error trying to update mapping and mapping does not change.) You should share more information -- including version of ES and steps to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change an analyzer, of course you need to reindex your data, or at the very least the field whose analyzer was changed.